# How to use custom VBA function in WHERE IN condition

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to use a custom VBA function to populate the list for the WHERE IN function of an access SQL query however I can't seem to get it working. A simplified version of the query is shown below

```
SELECT staffNo, [Staff Member], CoachingStage, 
FROM tblCoachingStages
WHERE CoachingReason IN (getList())
```

The code for the getList() function is

```
Function getList() As String

If DCount("[CDP]", "[tblAdmin]", "[CDP] = '" & Environ("username") & "'") = 0 Then
        getList= "'Performance', 'ReDeployment'"
Else
        getList= "'Performance', 'ReDeployment', 'Absence'"
End If

End Function
```

I have tried playing around with the quotes like missing the leading and end quotes in case this is added by the compiler but I can't get it working.

I'm trying to avoid using a queryDef to change the SQL of the query as the form loads on the open of the database and the query populates a sub form so if I change the sql on the load event of the form it has already run the query in the background.

Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? What do you get if you add a debug.print of your sql string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is going to work. Your function is returning you a **single string** value, so the `WHERE` clause is effectively coming out (depending on the result of your `DCOUNT` function) as either:

```
WHERE CoachingReason = "'Performance', 'ReDeployment'"
```

or

```
WHERE CoachingReason = "'Performance', 'ReDeployment', 'Absence'"
```

Maybe you could try

```
WHERE getList() Like "*" & CoachingReason & "*"
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in my reply, I had left the office on Friday before your answer. This works brilliantly, I hadn't thought to do it this way. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

@Skippy is right. The in-values must be resolved before running the query.

You could do:

```
SELECT 
    staffNo, [Staff Member], CoachingStage 
FROM 
    tblCoachingStages
WHERE 
    CoachingReason IN ('Performance', 'ReDeployment')
    OR
    CoachingReason = Nz(DLookup("'Absence'", "[tblAdmin]", "[CDP] = '" & Environ("username") & "'"))
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I'm going to go with Skippy's answer as the example question I posted was a bit simplified and the string returned by getlist can contain lots of different values so it's easier to just use the wildcard. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function getList, in a bas module with public keyword so it is accessible with Access Queries. For testing call the function from VBA code immediate window like ?getlist() and press enter. This should return you a result and not error. 
Once run your query with hardcoded values of the function return values, to make sure that the query syntax and SQL is OK when function returns string.

Comment: Hi Sham. Yes the query runs correctly with the hardcoded values. I was trying to get it to run with the function as part of the query. I'm going to go with Skippy's answer now, thanks